# WSo2: Rabbitmq is it possible to requeue from sequence without proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am working on simple Wso2 RabbitMQ integration. My inbound endpoints consume the message and send it to the sequence. The sequence then stores the message. Another on failure sequence currently logging the error. I am trying to send the message on the queue again from the sequence.

**SalesOrderQueueInboundEP**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="SalesOrderQueueInboundEP" onError="SalesOrderQueueErrorSeq" protocol="rabbitmq" sequence="SalesOrderQueueProcessSeq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">localhost</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port">5672</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">SalesOrderQueue</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">amq.direct</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.message.content.type">application/xml</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

**SalesOrderQueueProcessSeq**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="SalesOrderQueueProcessSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="Log payload" level="full"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($)" name="body_json_property" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <sequence key="SalesDBSeq"/>
</sequence>
```

**SalesOrderQueueErrorSeq**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="SalesOrderQueueErrorSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="Log error details in case of failure" level="full">
        <property name="MESSAGE" value="An unexpected error occurred."/>
        <property expression="$ctx:SYNAPSE_REST_API" name="REST_API"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="ERROR_CODE"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_DETAIL" name="ERROR_DETAIL"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_EXCEPTION" name="ERROR_EXCEPTION"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NMRhman,

I believe that you need to roll back the transaction if the messages go to the error sequence.

Can you add the following to the inbound sequence?

```
<parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.auto.ack">false</parameter>
<parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.auto.delete">false</parameter>
```

Also, add the following property which instructs to rollback the message in the error sequence.

```
<property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Modified sequences as follows.

**SalesOrderQueueInboundEP**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="SalesOrderQueueInboundEP" onError="SalesOrderQueueErrorSeq" protocol="rabbitmq" sequence="SalesOrderQueueProcessSeq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">localhost</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port">5672</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">SalesOrderQueue</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.auto.ack">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.auto.delete">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">amq.direct</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.message.content.type">application/xml</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

**SalesOrderQueueErrorSeq**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="SalesOrderQueueErrorSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="Log error details in case of failure" level="full">
        <property name="MESSAGE" value="An unexpected error occurred."/>
        <property expression="$ctx:SYNAPSE_REST_API" name="REST_API"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="ERROR_CODE"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_DETAIL" name="ERROR_DETAIL"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_EXCEPTION" name="ERROR_EXCEPTION"/>
    </log>
    
   <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   
<drop/>
</sequence>
```

Please try the above and share your feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

 ERROR_EXCEPTION = , Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">{'wee':'ee'}</text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2020-11-08 12:19:30,859]  INFO {RabbitMQConsumer} - The rejected message with message id: null and delivery tag: 2 on the queue: SalesOrderQueue will discard or dead-lettered.

Comment: So What I did, I intentionally put wrong DB connection pool to check. Basically, what I am after, queue the message until it successfully stored in DB.

Comment: When It tries to insert the message into DB it is getting "SQL Error while executing insert statement" as expected. Then it tries to Execute fault handler due to exception encountered. After that, I am getting that exception.

Comment: @MMRahman when the failure occurs, it rolls back the message to the rabbitMQ queue. then it will poll again and tries to store it in the database. hence, you can ensure that the message is not discarded if the failure happens at the persistent level.

Comment: @MMRahman you can define the `<parameter name="rabbitmq.message.max.dead.lettered.count">3</parameter>` in order to set the maximum retris before discard the message.

Comment: I tried  <parameter name="rabbitmq.message.max.dead.lettered.count">3</parameter>  and getting same error. Can I set delay parameter here?

Comment: We can define the polling interval from the queue inside the inbound endpoint configurations. `<parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>

Comment: I added this         <parameter name="rabbitmq.channel.consumer.qos">1</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.message.max.dead.lettered.count">3</parameter>
  <parameter name="rabbitmq.message.requeue.delay">30000</parameter>
. But no luck. However, My initial query is solved. I will do a couple of other checks and will let you.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can I get message header information from the queue. I can get payload using <property expression="json-eval($)" name="body_json_property" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Comment: You can use `<property name="stockprop" expression="$trp:Content-Type"/>' />` here you can retrieve the transport headers.